# Change domain in bar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'd like to change the domain of my D3 bar chart dynamically.

When I have ten bars lined up horizontally and call `changeDomain(2, 9);` I'd expect to see a subset of the bars (which are now wider) but have kept their original order (i.e., they have the same order as before the change in domain).

This is what I aim for when changing the domain:

[image]

Yet in my current implementation the bars get all mixed up.

Here is a fiddle to illustrate my problem: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/WYSqC/)

How can I change the bar chart's domain and keep the order of the bars?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you were looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/WYSqC/3/

```
// Refresh the bars
_bars = _bars.data(_dataset.slice(start-1,end-1));

_bars.attr(getBarAttributes());
_bars
     .enter()
     .append('rect')
     .attr(getBarAttributes());
_bars.exit().remove();
```